# Node.js - loop through JSON list of files to save locally using http.get

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, http

I have a JSON file that contains a list of file names on the server.  I need to loop through this list and save each file locally.  I have this working to a degree.  Sometimes it works like a charm, others it doesn't and I end up with empty files.

I get that this is probably starting to download the next file before the previous has finished but I am struggling to re write this so that I get a callback when the file is done to start downloading the next.  I am not that experienced with client side coding and so would really appreciate some help with this.

```
var filefolder = 'http://www.example.com/files/';
        var newdir = nw.App.dataPath;
        $.each(jsonFiles, function(i, fn) {
            //read and download to save locally
            var filelink = filefolder + '/' + fn;
            var newfile = fs.createWriteStream(newdir+'/files/' + '/' + fn);
            var request = http.get(filelink, function(response) {
                response.pipe(newfile );
                console.log(fn);
                newfile.on('finish', function() {
                    newfile.close(cb);
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: Seems like you have an async race issue.  Maybe try placing "var newfile = ..." inside the callback of "http.get...".  Then move the "response.pipe..." into the call back of "newfile.on('finish')"

Comment: Wrapping `http.get` call by closure with `filelink, newfile, fn & cb` as params might work

Comment: Thanks @josephnvu, tried your suggestion but then all of the files are empty, not just a few.

Comment: Sorry @Jaganathan Bantheswaran I'm not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Since your download code is inside `each` loop and `http.get` is async, you have to wrap the call with closure.

Something like this,

```
var filefolder = 'http://www.example.com/files/';
var newdir = nw.App.dataPath;
$.each(jsonFiles, function(i, fn) {
    //read and download to save locally
    var filelink = filefolder + '/' + fn;
    var newfile = fs.createWriteStream(newdir + '/files/' + '/' + fn);
   (function(filelink, newfile, fn, cb) {
       var request = http.get(filelink, function(response) {
                 response.pipe(newfile);
                 console.log(fn);
                 newfile.on('finish', function() {
                     newfile.close(cb);
                 });
             });
   })(filelink, newfile, fn, cb)
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Im still getting some empty files unfortunately  :(